# Data Through Year

Tags: prepositions, time

What does "data through" some year mean, like the following:

> [link](http://www.federalreserve.gov/pubs/ifdp/2006/883/ifdp883.htm)
>   Specifically, the short-run response based on ***data through 2005*** is smaller than the short-run response based on data through 2000.

Is there a dictionary definition that would fit this usage of "*through*"?

Answer (score 2):

See definition #4 in the [World English Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/through) (scroll down to it):

> *chiefly  ( US )* up to and including: *Monday through Friday*

I don't know why they put "US" in parentheses.

---

See definition #5 at the [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/through):

> *(North America)* To (or up to) and including, with all intermediate values.
>   *from 1945 **through** 1991;  the numbers 1 **through** 9;  your membership is active **through** March 15, 2013*

---

Those are just the first two I checked. I think most dictionaries would have this definition.

Comment: Would "data ***from*** through 2005" or "data ***from a period*** through 2005" be better?

Comment: "From through" doesn't make any sense to me. The pattern is "(from) X through Y". Personally I would use _until_ or _up to_ instead of _through_. I am not American.

Comment: Does that "*from*" in "*(from) X through Y*" mean "source" or "beginning"?

Comment: @meatie, yes, the _from_ is the beginning of the range.

Comment: So, the "*from*" in "data ***from*** 2000" would mean the beginning of some range?

Comment: "Data from 2005" with no mention of "through" is normally understood to mean that the data covers only the one year, 2005. "Date from 2005 through 2010" means for the period beginning with 2005 and ending with 2010. "Data through 2010" means a period ending with 2010, with the starting date not specified.

Comment: @Jay  So, the "*from*" in "Data ***from*** 2005" is different from the "*from*" in "Data ***from*** 2005 through 2010"?

Comment: @meatie Yes. "From" can indicate a source, as in "This juice comes from a lemon." It can also indicate the beginning of a range, as in "I work from 9 am to 5 pm." "Data from 2005" is using "from" in the first sense; "Data from 2005 through 2010" is using it in the second sense. (I can see how these two different uses in very similar sentences can be confusing.) If you want to use "from" as the start of a range without giving an end, you usually need to add a word or two to make that clear. Like, "We used data starting from 2005."

Comment: @Jay  In  "we used data starting from 2005", it seems that "starting from 2005" modifies "used", not data?

Comment: @meatie Hmm, I'd say it still modifies "data", because it is the data that is from 2005, that's not when you started using it. It would be plausible to say, "We began a study starting in 2014 that used data starting from 2005." The first "starting" phrase modifies "began", the second modified "data".

Comment: @Jay Would "data ***from from*** 2005 through 2010" be crystal clear, with the first "*from*" indication source and the second "*from*" indicating the beginning of some range?

Comment: @meatie Nobody says that. "data from 2005 through 2010" would be perfectly clear. The only time you'd use two "froms" would be if you were expressing a source as well as a range, like "data from the National Archives from 2005 through 2010", and then you wouldn't put the two "froms" in a row.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to data generated or collected **until the end** of the year 2005.

Comment: Would "data ***from*** through 2005" or "data ***from a period*** through 2005" be better?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether you are using American or British English.

In the US, it means *data collected up to and including 2005*.  In other words earlier years are included.

In Britain, it means *data collected throughout 2005*.  In other words, only during 2005.

The use of *through* as a synonym of *until* is not common outside the US.